# Implicit Broadcast Exceptions for Samsung Knox

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, samsung-knox

Are the following broadcasts exempted from implicit broadcast restrictions for apps that target Android O ( API 26 ) ?

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.ENTER_KNOX_DESKTOP_MODE" />
        <action android:name="android.app.action.EXIT_KNOX_DESKTOP_MODE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got confirmation from Samsung that they are also part of the exempted list.